# RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android, android-camera, runtimeexception

I searched a lot on StackOverflow about this error but have not been able to find a solution.

this is the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:351)
            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:325)
            at com.app.app.Scatta.surfaceCreated(Scatta.java:232)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the app crash when `Camera.open` is called inside `void surfaceCreated`

this is my code:

```
public class Scatta extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

  android.hardware.Camera camera;
  SurfaceView surfaceView;
  SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.scatta_layout);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_layout, null);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParams);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.relative_camera);
    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
        }
    });
```

...

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (camera == null){

        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(); ////////this is the row 232

        try{

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)  {

    if (previewing) {

        camera.stopPreview();

    }
    else  {

        android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90){
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(height, width);
        }
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }

        parameters.setFocusMode(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

        List<android.hardware.Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        size = sizes.get(0);

        parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

        camera.setParameters(parameters);

        Thread preview_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                camera.startPreview();
            }
        }, "preview_thread");
        preview_thread.start();

        previewing = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (camera != null){
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

and this is the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
 ...
```

**The strange thing is that in a Samsung Galaxy Core2 I can't see this issue, but in Honor 6 there is and also in simulator (Genymotion)**

**How is it possible that a device works but not on another, with the same version of Android?**

Comment: Did it happen the first time you opened it or only after the second try?

Comment: @GeorgeR this happen first time ever

Comment: try it  if (previewing) { camera.stopPreview(); camera.release();}

Comment: restart device and try agin

Comment: are you using wich android api?

Answer (score 0):

Write in your gradle.build targetSdkVersion 22. It is a temporary solution but work.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I changed much code in order to works :)